# How to require namespace inside function -main?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

Suppose that in Leiningen project yo, I have these files:

foo.clj:

```
(ns yo.foo)
(def x 234.5)
```

bar.clj:

```
(ns yo.bar)
(def x -15)
```

And I have a main file (core.clj):

```
(ns yo.core)
(require '[yo.foo :as f])
(when (= f/x 234.5) (println "Succesfully required foo."))
(defn -main [& args]
  (println (require '[yo.bar :as b]))
  ;(when (= b/x -15) (println "Succesfully required bar."))
 )
```

When I enter "lein run" on the command line, I get this output:

```
Succesfully required foo.
nil
```

The first line tells me that I understand how to use the `require` function at the top level of a file. (Normally I would use `:require` in the `ns` statement.)  The second line seems to indicate that I successfully required `yo.bar`.

However, when I uncomment the line containing `when` in `-main`, I get an exception:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: b, compiling:(yo/core.clj:6:9)`.

Is there a way to perform a require from inside a function?  My goal is to pass the name of a namespace on the command line, and have that namespace loaded as a result.  Is there another way to do this? (I already know how to access command line arguments from within `-main`.)

(The problem is not that I wrapped the `require` call with `println`.  I get the same exception if the first line of `-main` says only `(require '[yo.bar :as b])`.)

(The title of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584223/how-to-require-a-namespace-programmatically) makes it seem as if it's the same as mine, but the question and the answer don't address the problem of requiring a namespace from inside a function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `require` statement within the function `-main` is not invoked during compilation. Thus the compiler can't resolve the namespace `b` and complains.

Comment: I see.  i.e. the `require` does fire at runtime, but by then it's too late. Thanks Leon. This makes it sound as if there is no way to use namespaces that are chosen at runtime, except by explicitly calling the compiler or by throwing source code into a repl at runtime, or maybe using `load-file`. But I guess could use the method described in the question I linked to. That gets the namespace dynamically, but from the environment rather than by parsing command line arguments. If I wanted to pass the namespace on the command line, I could call `lein` from a shell script that sets an env var.

Comment: It turns out that I can pass code from the command line to `load-string` and have the newly loaded namespace recognized--which is what I wanted to do in the first place.  Since `load-string` also causes compilation at runtime, the fact that the namespace is compiled then as well is not a problem.

Comment: How is `(require ...)` invoked during compilation when it is a top-level statement?

Comment: @HappyFace Compilation effects to invoking all top level forms